# How can I change key value pair to an entry in json

Tags: json, key-value, key-pair

I have this JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "bmu_ftp_ip",
    "value": "148.72.213.234"
  },
  {
    "name": "bmu_ftp_path",
    "value": "/BMU/"
  },
...
]
```

The expected JSON looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "bmu_ftp_ip": "148.72.213.234",
  },
  {
    "bmu_ftp_path": "/BMU/",
  },
...
]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve expected JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like this:

```
(()=>{
var obj=[ { "name": "bmu_ftp_ip", "value": "148.72.213.234" }, { "name": "bmu_ftp_path", "value": "/BMU/" },]

obj.forEach((e)=>{
    e[e.name]=e.value;
    delete e.name;
    delete e.value;
})
```

})()